# SPFX-Tooling error No deploy CDN path specified(Updated)

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling

I am getting the following error out of gulp bundle --ship:

[10:44:11] Starting subtask 'copy-assets'...
[10:44:11] [copy-assets] No deploy CDN path specified. Unable to prepare production deployment.
[10:44:11] Finished subtask 'copy-assets' after 207 ms
[10:44:11] Starting subtask 'write-manifests'...
[10:44:11] [write-manifests] CDN deploy path not specified. Unable to produce production manifests.
[10:44:11] Finished subtask 'write-manifests' after 528 ms

I have set up my cdnBasePath in write-manifest.json like this:
{
   "cdnBasePath": "https://rgove3.sharepoint.com/sites/cdn/spfxapps/propertybageditor"
}

and my deployCdnPath in prepare-deploy.json like this:

{
  "deployCdnPath": "temp/deploy"
}

anybody got an idea what the build tools are complaining about.

[11:00:46] Build tools version: 2.4.0
[11:00:46] Node version: v6.9.2

**UPDATE:**
running gulp bundle --ship --verbose
showed me this :
D:\sp-dev-fx-webparts\samples\react-property-bag-editor (dev) (react-property-bag-editor@0.0.1)
λ gulp bundle --ship --verbose
Build target: SHIP
Found config file: config.json
Found config file: tslint.json
Found config file: write-manifests.json
Found config file: serve.json
Found config file: deploy-azure-storage.json
Found config file: package-solution.json
[17:48:36] Using gulpfile D:\sp-dev-fx-webparts\samples\react-property-bag-editor\gulpfile.js
[17:48:36] Starting gulp
[17:48:36] Starting 'bundle'...
[17:48:36] Starting subtask 'pre-copy'...
[17:48:36] Finished subtask 'pre-copy' after 9.97 ms

on amother project , where the bundle command was working the same command showd me this:
       D:\sp-dev-fx-webparts\samples\react-videolibrary (dev) (videotst@0.0.1)
λ gulp bundle --ship --verbose
Build target: SHIP
Found config file: config.json
Found config file: tslint.json
Schema file D:\sp-dev-fx-webparts\samples\react-videolibrary\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-common\lib\schemas\tslint.schema.json not found
Found config file: serve.json
Schema file D:\sp-dev-fx-webparts\samples\react-videolibrary\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-web\lib\schemas\serve.schema.json not found
Found config file: deploy-azure-storage.json
Schema file D:\sp-dev-fx-webparts\samples\react-videolibrary\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-web\lib\schemas\deploy-azure-storage.schema.json not found
Found config file: package-solution.json
Schema file D:\sp-dev-fx-webparts\samples\react-videolibrary\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-web\lib\schemas\package-solution.schema.json not found
Found config file: prepare-deploy.json
Schema file D:\sp-dev-fx-webparts\samples\react-videolibrary\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-web\lib\schemas\copy-assets.schema.json not found
Found config file: write-manifests.json
Schema file D:\sp-dev-fx-webparts\samples\react-videolibrary\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-web\lib\schemas\write-manifests.schema.json not found
Found config file: tslint.json
Found config file: serve.json
Found config file: package-solution.json
[17:50:52] Using gulpfile D:\sp-dev-fx-webparts\samples\react-videolibrary\gulpfile.js
[17:50:52] Starting gulp
[17:50:52] Starting 'bundle'...
[17:50:52] Starting subtask 'pre-copy'...

The output of this showed that it found the prepare-deploy.json  file. The output from the other did not.

I tried deleting the prepare-deploy.json file, but that did not fix the problem.

Comment: So, my deployCdnPath is defined in copy-assets.json, not prepare-deploy.json.  Can you dump the devDependencies section of your package.json file?

Comment: Hi Pat, here it is:"devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "~1.0.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "~1.0.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "@types/chai": ">=3.4.34 <3.6.0",
    "@types/mocha": ">=2.2.33 <2.6.0"
  },

Comment: project is at https://github.com/russgove/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/dev/samples/react-property-bag-editor

Comment: my copy assets had this:{
  "solution": {
    "name": "react-property-bag-editor-client-side-solution",
    "id": "12dac38e-b255-44ce-9f06-050571b34d39",
    "version": "1.0.0.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "zippedPackage": "solution/react-property-bag-editor.sppkg",
     "deployCdnPath": "temp/deploy"
  }
}

Comment: I replaced it with:{
  "deployCdnPath": "temp/deploy"
}

Comment: now it works fine

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Try:

gulp serve

Gulp bundle --production

Look this step by step to publish:  http://www.pedromneto.com/publicando-client-webpart-sharepoint-framework-no-sharepoint-online/

Comment: I did gulp serve and gulp bundle --production. λ gulp bundle --production --sane issue
Build target: SHIP
[
[15:43:08] [copy-assets] No deploy CDN path specified. Unable to prepare production deployment.
[15:43:08] Finished subtask 'copy-assets' after 166 ms
[15:43:08] Starting subtask 'write-manifests'...
[15:43:08] [write-manifests] CDN deploy path not specified. Unable to produce production manifests.
...[15:43:09] Build tools version: 2.4.0
[15:43:09] Node version: v6.9.2
[15:43:09] Total duration: 21

Comment: were you using the GA tools?

Answer (score 0):

I added a file called **copy-assets.json** to the config directory with the text :

```
{
  "deployCdnPath": "temp/deploy"
}
```

and the command gulp --ship and / or gulp bundle --production started working.

No idea why it can't read the value from prepare-deploy.json which has the same value in it.

Maybe a little documentation would clear this up ?